# why the height of the out div is affected by vertical-align

Tags: html, css

in chrome, I thought the height of .wrap should be 24px.

it is 25px when the vertial-align is set to middle. can someone explain why?

answer in [this article](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align)

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.wrap {
  font-size:16px;  /* 16*1.5= 24 */
}

.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="btn">
    OK
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: i have set box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As It is explained [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

> Aligns the middle of the element with the baseline plus half the
>   x-height of the parent.

The line-height of your .wrap element is by default 1.5 that inherits from the body, the vertical align property will render depending on your line-height, so if the line height is bigger than your wrapper element, you will see the effect. to fix it just put line-height in your .wrap class, you can play with it to see how the line-height affects the vertical alignment.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.wrap {
  line-height:1;
  background:red;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="btn">
    OK
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: so it is trying to align the 12th pixel to the 13th pixel?

Comment: Something like this. [This article](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align) explains a bit better how vertical alignment moves the inline boxes in CSS (especially the part discussing the 'strut' of the parent block).

Comment: Although I still can't understand the explanation, line-height 1 did solve my problem. But if there are nested elements within .wrap, is the correct way to add a line-height: 1 to each layer?

Comment: Take this example, if I change .wrap to display: inline-block, the body will be raised again, does this have something to do with inline-block? I’m sure inline-flex doesn’t have this problem

Comment: example from the question (not the answer), if i change .btn to be vertical-align: top or vertical-align: bottom, its fixed the problem...what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements (for whatever reason) are surrounded by whitespace.
Changing the element to `display: block` will fix your problem but there are other ways to fix it whilst keeping it inline.

One way would be to set `font-size: 0` on the `.wrap` element as the whitespace is governed by font size. In this instance that would be fine as you are setting a font size on the child button (beware when using `em`s as they are relative to the parent font size).

More options can be found here - https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

**Solving the problem:**

Simply you're getting the extra pixel because of this:

```
body {
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

All your HTML elements are inheriting this attribute from the body.

**Answering the question:**

> why the height of the out div is affected by vertical-align

The `<button>` default display attribute is "inline-block", which gets affects by white-spaces, line-height, font-size, and other text-related CSS attributes. vertical-align is one of these text-related attributes. For example, if you change the button's display to "block" you can see that it no longer affects the `.wrap`'s height.

Answer (score -2):

Please give block CSS for the btn

```
.btn { display: block;}
```

Why block and not inline-block??

Elements in the inline formatting context will cause white spaces from carriage returns and white-spaces in your HTML
The inline-block value is incredibly useful when wanting to control margin and padding on "inline" elements without the need to `block and float` them.  One problem that arrises when you use inline-block is that whitespace in HTML becomes visual space on screen.

This isn't a "bug" (I don't think). It's just the way setting elements on a line works. You want spaces between words that you type to be spaces right? The spaces between these blocks are just like spaces between words.

So thats OK!

Comment: I know. but can you explain why it is 25px when .btn is inline-block

Comment: but still why 25px? 14px * 1.5 = 24